# Mouse keeps randomly clicking around the screen

Tags: windows-8, drivers, troubleshooting, touchscreen

I just reinstalled Windows 8 on my Dell XPS 15 touchscreen laptop and I am having a strange problem. My mouse (apparently) randomly jumps around the screen and clicks something. I was having this problem before I had to reinstall, but it's much more noticable now and is making my computer practically unusable. It has happened 4 times since I started writin...make that 5 times. Once it tried to close the window, another it clicked an ad, another time it minimized all, etc. No apparent pattern.

I have disabled the trackpad and unplugged the mouse and it still happens. I'm up to date on as many drivers as dell will let me download and I am getting to my wits' end.

Comment: Can you try boot a live CD OS (either Windows based or Linux based) and see if the problem persist? I suspect it's a hardware problem

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your keyboard for a sticky key, or debris between the keys?

I have seen similar behavior when the "snap to" option in your mouse settings is enabled and one of your enter keys is sticking.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's time for a new mouse and/or mouse driver software.

Comment: According to the question, the problem persists despite updated drivers and even without a mouse present at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this is a known problem with dell xps machine. You need to disable te sick light function on the keyboard. If you search dell forum you will find solution

Comment: Can you add some more specifics? This answer is pretty weak without more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my Lenovo yoga pro 2,the mouse would just jump around and select thing. I tried different setting for the mouse but it didn't work. I ended up uninstalling the mouse and point devices driver and it fixed the problem so far. If you uninstall it, when you restart the computer it automatically reinstalls the driver for you. It asked me if I wanted to delete it and restart now, I just didn't check that box for deleting and selected ok restart now.